# Procedure call inside procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

First I need to check if `spOBJ_CopyInspectiontask` has any errors, if there are no errors, only then proceed to the insert statement.

```
DECLARE @tblSystemId TABLE
                     (
                         OldSysId int, NewSysId int,
                         OldTaskId int, NewTaskId int,
                         TaskObjectIds varchar(max) null
                     );

INSERT INTO @tblSystemId (OldSysId , NewSysId, OldTaskId, NewTaskId, TaskObjectIds)            
    EXEC dbo.spOBJ_CopyInspectiontask @UserId, @TargetCustomerId, @TargetContractId, @TargetSiteId, @SourceCustomerId, @OldTaskId, @SystemName, @Checkall, @CopyReports, @Return OUTPUT, @ObjectIds OUTPUT;
```

How can I check that?

Comment: By default in MS SQL Server implicit transaction for insert should be started. So in case of any errors during call to dbo.spOBJ_CopyInspectiontask entire transaction will be rolled back and no rows inserted to @tblSystemId by this statement. Why you;re not satisfied by default behaviour I descibed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want a try/catch block:

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO @tblSystemId (OldSysId , NewSysId, OldTaskId, NewTaskId,TaskObjectIds )            
        EXEC dbo.spOBJ_CopyInspectiontask @UserId,@TargetCustomerId, @TargetContractId, @TargetSiteId,
             @SourceCustomerId, @OldTaskId, @SystemName, @Checkall, @CopyReports, @Return OUTPUT, @ObjectIds OUTPUT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- do something here in the event of failure
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Let me try... Thank you

Comment: Working Fine. Thank you